# Auto Refresh an xml file after editing

Tags: php, html, xml

I have an XML file that I edit everytime the user wants via a php script.
I'd love the XML file to refresh automatically after the script ends but this isn't happening. I know this could be a cache problem but i use this in every HTML page:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

and this changes nothing.

The only way to make it work is to open the XML file with the browser (when I do this there are not the edits I've made with the script) and shift+F5 it so the edits are there and everything works fine.
Is there any way possible to make the php script or a javascript function or anything to do this automatically????

Comment: What's the context? Are you displaying the XML file content in a textbox or something?

Comment: I use the xml as a "database" and display some fields depending on the page!

Comment: Is the XML file being parsed and displayed on the page by JavaScript or by PHP?

Comment: It's displayed by Javascript

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you can try setting the "cache" setting in the request to "false". See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/